# I.V.P. $\frac{dy}{dx}=f(y),y(0)=a.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the I.V.P. $$\frac{dy}{dx}=f(y(x)),y(0)=a\in\mathbb{R}$$ where $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}.$  which of the following statements are necessarily true?

$1.$ There exist a continuous function $f$ and a real number $a$ such that the above problem does not have a solution in any neighbourhood of zero.

$2$. The above problem has a unique solution for ever real $a$ when $f$ is Lipschitz continuous.

$3.$ When$f$ is twice continuously differentiale the maximum interval of existence for the above problem is $\mathbb{R}$.

$4.$ The maximum interval of existence for the above problem is $\mathbb{R}$ when $f$ is bounded and continuously differentiable.

According to me by Picard existence and uniqueness theorem first option is false and second one is true. I have no result regarding existence of solution in whole real line $\mathbb{R}$. For option number three I have counter example if $y =y^{2}$ .Please suggest me some result regarding this so that I can understand last option.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you mean $dy/dx = f(y)$ or $f(x)$?

Comment: So, $(f\circ y)(x)$ a.k.a. $f(y(x))$?

Comment: It's fine the way it was originally written, the notation is clear.